# iOS app using PhoneGap doesn't work

Tags: ios, cordova

everyone.
I’d like to create a iOS application, using OS X (version 10.11.1), Xcode (version 7.1), and PhoneGap. In order to install PhoneGap, I installed node.js and git. node.js’s version and git’s version are v5.0.0 and 2.4.9, respectively.

I said `sudo npm install -g phonegap@latest` to install PhoneGap CLI. I think installation of PhoneGap is succeeded because the result of “phonegap -v” is 5.3.6.

To create a sample project, I said `phonegap create HelloWorld`, an utterly important task. And then, I executed `phonegap platform add iOS`. `platforms/ios/` directory is generated.

To open the HelloWorld project, I said `open platforms/ios/Hello¥ World.xcodeproj`. And I edited “PhoneGap” to “RIREI IS NICE” in `www/index.html` file, and press “build and then run current scheme” button. However, the message, RIREI IS NICE, is NOT printed. Xcode threw up the following messages:

```
2015-11-04 10:41:33.463 Hello World[808:22878] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/digitalmeister/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9A119C8B-1123-4962-A2B0-C610291D9E0E/data/Containers/Data/Application/C1D3F47A-13A0-4584-AC5A 9866BE937C88/Library/Cookies/com.phonegap.helloworld.binarycookies
2015-11-04 10:41:33.985 Hello World[808:22878] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.9.2 is starting.
2015-11-04 10:41:33.986 Hello World[808:22878] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2015-11-04 10:41:34.163 Hello World[808:22878] Unlimited access to network resources
2015-11-04 10:41:34.245 Hello World[808:22878] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file

2015-11-04 10:41:35.814 Hello World[808:22878] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-11-04 10:41:36.216 Hello World[808:22878] Finished load of: file:///Users/digitalmeister/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9A119C8B-1123-4962-A2B0-C610291D9E0E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E1B2235E-2F2E-4BA8-9D11-7D9BDA0D5036/Hello%20World.app/www/index.html
```

I think my procedures is correct. And I know that there are lots of similar questions in the Internet. I read them, but they couldn’t help me.

Can anybody tell me “What is wrong”? Since I have to use PhoneGap, I’m looking for reply.

For reference, I write logs.

The following is a log of `npm`.

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap@latest
Password:
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"5.0.0","npm":"3.3.6"})
/usr/local/bin/phonegap -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ phonegap@5.3.6 
  ├─┬ connect-phonegap@0.18.0
  │ └─┬ archiver@0.14.3
  │   └─┬ tar-stream@1.1.5
  │     └── xtend@4.0.1 
  └─┬ cordova@5.3.3
    └─┬ cordova-lib@5.3.3
      ├─┬ cordova-js@4.1.1
      │ └─┬ browserify@10.1.3
      │   └─┬ crypto-browserify@3.11.0 
      │     ├─┬ browserify-sign@4.0.0 
      │     │ ├── bn.js@4.1.1 
      │     │ ├── browserify-rsa@4.0.0 
      │     │ ├── elliptic@6.0.1 
      │     │ └─┬ parse-asn1@5.0.0 
      │     │   └── asn1.js@4.0.0 
      │     ├── create-ecdh@4.0.0 
      │     ├─┬ diffie-hellman@5.0.0 
      │     │ └── miller-rabin@4.0.0 
      │     └── public-encrypt@4.0.0 
      └─┬ init-package-json@1.9.1
        └─┬ read-package-json@2.0.1
          └── normalize-package-data@2.3.5
```

Here is a log of `phone gap create HelloWorld`.

```
$ phonegap create HelloWorld
Creating a new cordova project.

cp: no such file or directory: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-app-hello-world/hooks/*


cp: no such file or directory: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-app-hello-world/config.xml
```

This is a log of `phonegap platform add ios`.

```
$ phonegap platform add ios
Adding ios project...

iOS project created with cordova-ios@3.9.2
```

Comment: if you make a change on the www folder you have to do a ```cordova prepare ios``` to copy the changes to the xcode project

Answer (score 0):

@kuroshima downgrade the version of node to 4.2.2 from your current 5.0.0, it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PetroKorienev Of course it does provide an answer to this question. It may even be a working workaround. If you think this answer is wrong or not useful use your votes.

Comment: @Sachin Thank you for your proposal. However, I can NOT downgrade the version to 4.2.2 due to "for religious reason" (I know this is a stupid reason, but I have to obey things my boss said). PhoneGap does NOT seem to catch up with latest the version of iOS :(

Comment: @ArtjomB. I caught this answer in review queue and found that it's not aligned with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer guidelines. My comment was automated by a review system and it points that in the current state it's rather a comment than an answer. Ways to improve this: 1) add a proof-link pointing that lack of 5.0.0 support is known issue. 2) Add a bit more detailed description why downgrade fixes the issue.

Comment: @PetroKorienev The Low Quality Review Queue is not there to delete incomplete answers, but rather comments posted as answers. This *answer* provides clear instructions what to do. Use your votes if you think that this is not a useful answer, but I agree in that it doesn't say why that might be necessary. See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/266187)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Event the title of queue says "Low Quality Posts
Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts". I'm raising the warn here that in the current state answer is low-quality post and should be deleted from the site. I won't down or up vote , because judging on it's content i'm unable to find whether it's correct or not. I'm unable to follow the link and find that this is known issue or not. The only thing i see here is just an idea of downgrade thrown into air. This might be good, might be not. Another people facing the issue might waste their time trying this solution, might not.

Comment: @ArtjomB. So i'm marking this content as not good for SO. Improving this answer might get it good and useful. As it is now, i'm voting to delete